# How can I route a url to a CGI script in Rack?

Tags: rack

I have an app that has a `htdocs` folder with static files and a couple of CGI scripts on the `httpd/cgi-bin` folder. How can I use Rack with `config.ru` to serve this application?

My current `config.ru`:

```
map "/check" do
  What here  ("httpd/cgi-bin/check_wrapper.sh")
end

run Rack::Directory.new("htdocs")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60) to run the command and grab the output.

```
map "/check" do
  run Proc.new { |env| [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, [`./httpd/cgi-bin/check_wrapper.sh`] ] } 
end

run Rack::Directory.new("htdocs")
```